# Can’t find Swift umbrella header

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

My project depends on my own framework. In the framework I started to implement some functionality with `Swift`.

Therefore I needed the import statement `#import "Appmodule-Swift.h"` in some of my `Obj-C` files inside the framework.

All works fine inside the framework, but as soon as it is imported into the project (through cocoa pods), the `#import "Appmodule-Swift.h"`  creates a compile time `file not found` error.

So basically how can you create a framework using cocoa pods which uses both `Obj-C` and `Swift`?

Is there anything particular you need to add to the `Podspec` file?

Comment: Note, that the `...-Swift.h` file is not the umbrella header, but the generated header. The umbrella header is the file where you need to import your Objective-C Headers when you want to use them in Swift.